# Definition of conditional independence on wikipedia

Tags: probability, independence

There are some questions about this wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence), but I want to focus on this particular part of the definition, which I can't find anyone ask before.

[image]

I don't understand why they can imply Pr(B|C) = 1. Can you have some explanation for me? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry, this is my first question. I will notice the rule. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think:
$P(A|B\cap C)=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)}=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)} \frac{P(C)}{P(B\cap C)} = \frac{P(A \cap B|C)}{P(B|C)} = \frac{P(A|C)P(B|C)}{P(B|C)} = P(A|C)$. 
Accordingly, we can say that $P(B|C)\neq 0$.

Comment: But the article says that P(B|C) = 1.

Comment: yes, according to me it is incorrect.